# How to get SparkContext if Spark runs on Yarn?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

We have a program based on Spark standalone, and in this program we use `SparkContext` and `SqlContext` to do lots of queries.

Now we want to deploy the system on a Spark which runs on Yarn. But when we modify the `spark.master` to `yarn-cluster`, the application throws an exception says this works with `spark-submit` type only. When we switch to `yarn-client`, although it no longer throws exceptions, it doesn't work properly.

It seems that if runs on Yarn, we can no longer use `SparkContext` to work, instead we should use something like `yarn.Client`, but in this way we don't know how to change our code to achieve what we have done before using `SparkContext` and `SqlContext`.

Is there a good way to solve this? Can we get `SparkContext` from `yarn.Client` or we should change our code to utilize new interfaces of `yarn.Client`?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you: post your code & elaborate on "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: @Holden sorry for my vague question. I'm not so familiar with spark when I raised the problem. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131826/spark-on-yarn-job-failed-with-exitcode1-and-stderr-says-cant-find-main-class to view details about the problem we are facing now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you run on cluster , you need to do a spark-submit like this

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
```

--master will be yarn
--deploy-mode will be cluster

In your application if you have something like setMaster("local[]") , you can remove it and build the code. when you do spark-submit with --Master yarn, yarn will launch containers for you instead of spark-standalone scheduler.

Your app code can look like this without any setting for Master

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App Name")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

yarn deploy mode client is use when you want to launch driver on same machine from code is running. On a cluster the deploy mode should be cluster, this will make sure driver is launched on one of the worker node by yarn.